# How do I break a stack of objects?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Either it's impossible, or I'm being dense, but how do I break a stack of objects in to smaller stacks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold Alt, click on the stack, then click an empty inventory slot.

Comment: You should probably note that this is new as of one of the recent patches, @Michael was correct when he posted originally.

Comment: Ah, they've patched it have they? Nice. I'll have to double check when I get home before moving the tick over, but in the meantime does this split the stack in half? Or just pull off one item? etc? Oh, and do you know what version this was available from?

Comment: @DMA57361 Alt-clicking on a stack of items will pull one item from the stack and put it on your cursor. You can hold Alt and click multiple times to pick up more than one item from the stack.

Answer (score 5):

Drop a stack on a crafting item slot - open (for example), the forge and then drop the stack on a slot.  The first time an item is placed in a crafting slot it will only drop one item.  The second time, it will drop the rest of the stack.  This way, you can make a stack of 10 into a stack of 1 and 9.  Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Well that works, so +1, but it feels ... wrong. If that's the only way then we'll have to assume oversight by the devs I guess, will leave this a little longer in case another answer crops up.

Comment: It's clunky alright: good luck converting your stack of 88 softballs to lutefisk. I think it would be best if the conversion took stacksize into account; for most other cases the existing mechanism is okayish. Selling is usually an all-or-nothing thing for me, anyway.

Comment: As of patch 1.0.9, this no longer works.