# How do I split item stacks?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I had two ingot presses. I'd like to sell one, but I can't find a way to split the stack. [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/26331/6914) provides a work-around involving placing stacks in crafting screens, but that doesn't work for the crafting items. Placing my smelters in the smithing kit didn't separate them. Placing them in themselves didn't do it. Placing them in the Lutefisk Cube turned them both into lutefisk!

I'd like to avoid another lutefisk incident. How can I split stacks of crafting items?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ALT-Click on the item you want to split :)

Comment: Have you confirmed this to work on crafting items like the ingot press and alchemy kit? I thought I had tried ALT-clicking, but I will try again when I get home.

Comment: I haven't tried it on crafting items, but it should work normally. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Works for everything except crafting items, unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't work in Linux/GNOME, where ALT-Clicking a window allows you to move it.

Comment: @Arkive I just tested this out in the v1.0.9 Windows version and Alt-clicking on crafting items seems to work now.

Comment: Just chiming in to confirm jaminja's finding - with 1.0.9B on Windows I have succesfully split stacks of Ingot Presses and Anvils.

Comment: I just confirmed that alt+clicking (or rather Option+clicking) does work for the Mac on split stacks of all kinds.

Comment: As @Broam says, ALT+Click doesn't work in GNU/Linux (it's used to move the window), so CTRL+ALT+Click must be used.